# emberjs using multiple paths / urls for one route

Tags: javascript, url, ember.js, routes, view

In Ember I can use this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('accomodations');
});
```

so if one goes to /accomodations it will load that view.

I can also add:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('accomodations', { path: '/travel' });
});
```

so if one goes to /travel, it will go to the same view.

I want to be able to have /accomodations  and /travel go to the same view? is this possible?

I know that this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('accomodations');
    this.route('accomodations', { path: '/travel' });
});
```

Will do what I'm asking, but if they go to accommodations, it should show that in the url, it always shows travel.  I'm not even sure if the final piece of code is best practice.

Comment: I believe you're looking for [redirection](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/redirection/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using redirection

In `router.js`

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('accomodations');
    this.route('travel');
});
```

In `routes/travel.js`

```
App.TravelRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('accomodations');
    },
});
```

You do not have to put these in separate files (that's just where I would put them).

What this does is register two routes with the router. Pick one of them to be the "main" route, and the other the "alias" route. In this case, `accomodation` is the main route, and `travel` is its alias. When the user visits `/travel`, they get redirected to `/accomodation`.

This would be the default/ standard Ember way of accomplishing this, and if this sounds good to you, go for this.

#### Another possible solution

If you do not wish to have redirection happen, for some reason, and want the URL seen by the user to stay the same, but still display the same things, and behave in the same way, this is also possible.

In this case, you would create two of every single Ember unit (route, controller, view, template). The smart way would be to create a base class route, and have both `App.TravelRoute` and `App.AccomodationRoute` trivially extend it; create a base class controller, and have both `App.TravelController` and `App.AccomodationController` trivially extend it; same for views, if you have them.

Templates, OTOH, are a little trickier, because there is not way to extend them (that I know of). SO what you would need to do, is create either a partial or a component (decided which works better for you), and then reuse that partial/ component in both `templates/accomodation.hbs` and `templates/travel.hbs`

Comment: for templates you can use symlinks

Comment: This doesn’t seem to work. After calling `this.transitionTo('route')`, nothing happens. The hooks of `'route'` are not executed.

Comment: @kleinfreund You might need to use a version of EmberJs from 2014 for this to work

Answer (score 7):

You can simply interchange the two route-path definition lines:

```
App.Router.map(function() {

     this.route('accomodations', { path: '/travel' });
     this.route('accomodations');
});
```

The last definition takes the precedence for URL display in `{{link-to ...'accomodations'}}` and `Route#transitionTo('accomodations')` in-app transitions, though entering the app by '/travel' will leave the URL as is.
(*EmberJS* 1.11.3, 2.12.2)

Comment: this behaviour has been changed in Ember 2.10, you cannot use it like that anymore.

Comment: I also am not sure this solution would work if you were doing a multi-level route. (i.e. `hat` -> `products/hats`).

Comment: I just tried it with Ember 3.26.1 and it works great.  Both routes work and neither updates the URL (one doesn't redirect to the other).