# Ember Optional URL Segments

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-routing

Is there a way in Ember to have optional segments in a url?

That is I have the :locale in `/:locale/reservations/:id` be optional so that `/fr/reservations/12345` works as well as `/reservations/12345`?

My current router looks like this:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'reservation', path: '/*locale/reservations/:id', ->
    @route('status', path: '/status')
```

Comment: You can do it in `serialize`.

Comment: Can you be more specific how `serialize` helps?  Not sure what I'd do in the serialize method.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here [emberjs using multiple paths / urls for one route](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24923120/2429040) or in `serialize` try smthing like:

```
serialize: function(model, params) {
  var locale, id;

  if(model.locale)
    locale = model.locale;
  else
    locale = '';

  id  = model.id;
  return { locale: locale, id: id };
}
```